# I can't create a list of dictionary from excel file

Tags: python, list, dictionary

this is my code. I read an excel file with pandas

```
    import pandas as pd

    df = pd.read_excel('people.xlsx')
    print(df.to_dict())
    
    user = {}
    list_of_user = []
    
    for i in range(len(df)):
        user['name'] = (df['name'][i])
        user['surname'] = (df['surname'][i])
        user['email'] = (df['email'][i])
        user['interest'] = (df['interest'][i])
        print(user)
        list_of_user.append(user)
    
    print(list_of_user)
```

This is the result

```
        {'name': {0: 'John', 1: 'Marry', 2: 'Dmitri'}, 'surname': {0: 'Smith', 1: 'Smith', 2: 'Kery'}, 'email': {0: 'a@com', 1: 'a1@com', 2: 'a2@com'}, 'interest': {0: 'money', 1: 'gadget', 2: 'nasa'}}
        user = {'name': 'John', 'surname': 'Smith', 'email': 'a@com', 'interest': 'money'}
        user = {'name': 'Marry', 'surname': 'Smith', 'email': 'a1@com', 'interest': 'gadget'}
        user = {'name': 'Dmitri', 'surname': 'Kery', 'email': 'a2@com', 'interest': 'nasa'}
        list_of_user =  [{'name': 'Dmitri', 'surname': 'Kery', 'email': 'a2@com', 'interest': 'nasa'}, {'name': 'Dmitri', 'surname': 'Kery', 'email': 'a2@com', 'interest': 'nasa'}, {'name': 'Dmitri', 'surname': 'Kery', 'email': 'a2@com', 'interest': 'nasa'}]
```

Why in list_of_user I have 3 identical users?

Comment: You are reusing the user variable without reinitializing it. Dictionary variables are references, not values. So it is like having `[user, user, user]` where user is the same thing.

Comment: Thank you. I add user = {} at the beginning of the loop and its work.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use:

list_of_user.append({user.items()})

instead.

Comment: I tried but I got an error.  TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict_items'

Comment: Just faced almost the same problem trying to add a list of np.arrays to a list... The origin of OUR problem is that dict and list are mutable types. So, the most reliable (I guess) solution is to use .copy() method:  list_of_user.append(user.copy()).